# error class "... is public should be declared in a file named..." but names match

Tags: java

The file is named `scriptletTestsScriptlet.java` (yep it's a stupid name, also jasper scritplets are supposed to start with lower case which seems to interfere with standard java class naming)

unfortunately even though the class name and the file name match I still get the error

> java: class scriptletTestsScriptlet is public, should be declared in a file named scriptletTestsScriptlet.java

I've literally copy pasted the file name out of the error.

Intellij doesn't seem to have a problem with the package or the class name either. If I change them to incorrect values it does complain.

```
package com.marinecyb.hilit2.nbm.gui.export;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDefaultScriptlet;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRScriptletException;

public class scriptletTestsScriptlet extends JRDefaultScriptlet {

    public void afterDetailEval() throws JRScriptletException {

          String iGotMine = (String)this.getVariableValue("heading");
          this.setVariableValue("scriptletOutput", iGotMine + ": Hello World");

    }
}
```

Comment: "**scriptletTestsScriptlet.jave**" <-- is this a typo in the question?

Comment: Are you writing a constructor for this class in the name of afterDetailEval() ???

Comment: typo. fixed now

Even if i comment out afterDetailEval method it still gives me the error.

Comment: It looks like it *HAS* to be capital first. Once I changed the class and file name to ScriptletTestsScriptlet it compiled correctly. Go figure.

Comment: @AntonMaes: [It is OK to answer your own questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)